# Batch File delete newest file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do you all delete the newest file in a folder using batch script?

All results I have found ONLY show how to delete the oldest files or delete them after N days.

Links are : [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days?rq=1) and [Batch Script to delete oldest folder in a given folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466638/batch-script-to-delete-oldest-folder-in-a-given-folder)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /B /O-D /A-D %the_directory%') do echo("%the_directory%\%%a"&goto deldone
:deldone
```

would be my approach. It rudely escapes from the `for` loop having deleted the first filename encountered in a sorted-in-reverse-date-order (`/o-d`) list.

This saves having to read the entire list. Not such a problem with a few files, but can be a pain with thousands.

The required DEL command is merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the command is correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

Comment: I thought of this method as well, but although the performance is for sure better, I decided not to use it here as it might cause trouble if inserted into a script in case it is placed within another parenthesised block of code...

Comment: @aschipfl: fair enough, but there are limits. With your example, you'd possibly get better performance with `if not defined file set "file=%%F"`.

Comment: Ah, yes, querying the variable might be faster than multiplicately overwriting it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
@echo off
set latest=
set the_directory=your_directory

for /F %%a in ('dir /B /OD /A-D %the_directory%') do set latest=%%a

del %the_directory%\%latest%
```

run `dir` on files only, with sorting on modification date. Then loop and keep last echoed file. Delete it (replace by `echo` to test!)

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet does what you want:

```
set "FILE="
pushd "\path\to\folder" || exit /B 1
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:C "*.*"
') do (
    set "FILE=%%F"
)
if defined FILE del "%FILE%"
popd
```

The `dir` command returns files only (`/A:-D`) sorted by date in ascending order (`/O:D`) using the **creation date** (`/T:C`), which are located in `\path\to\folder` and match the pattern `*.*`.
The `for /F` loop walks through all the files returned by `dir` and assigns its name to variable `FILE`, overwriting it in each iteration, hence the final value is the name of the newest file.
The `del` command finally deletes the found file. The `if` query covers the case when no files are found in the given location.

---

Here is a slightly modified variant as recommended by Magoo's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440266/batch-file-delete-newest-file/40440411#comment68127831_40440411), which might be a bit more performant than the aforementioned one:

```
set "FILE="
pushd "\path\to\folder" || exit /B 1
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:-D /T:C "*.*"
') do (
    if not defined FILE set "FILE=%%F"
)
if defined FILE del "%FILE%"
popd
```

This avoids multiplicately overwriting of variable `FILE` by querying whether it has already been defined. Note the reversed sort order of `dir` here.

However, the approach shown in Magoo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440411) is still better in performance.